# Creating a method from calling two classes in java

Tags: java, object, methods, arraylist

I'm not sure which one of my methods that's not working. When i create accounts from addSavingsAccount everything is working fine, but when I want to print out the info from two classes it prints name and pNr but shows the first accountnumber to all clients. What's wrong with this?

```
//this works fine
public int addSavingsAccount(long pNr){ 

    for(int i = 0; i < customerlist.size(); i++)
    {
        if(customerlist.get(i).getPCode() == pNr)
        {
            Customer customer = customerlist.get(i);
            customer.addAccount(pNr);
            return account.getAccountId();
        }
    }
    return -1;
}


//but this don't
public String infoAccount(long pNr, int accountId)
{
    String info = "";
    for(Customer customer : customerlist) {
          if(customer.getPCode() == pNr) {
            this.customer = customer;
            ArrayList<SavingsAccount> accounts = customer.getAccount();
            for (SavingsAccount account : accounts) {
              this.account = account;
              if (account.getAccountId() == accountId){
                info = account.toString();
            }
            }
        }
     } 
    return info;
}

//this was my first try of printing out:
public String infoAccount(long pNr, int accountId)
{
    String info = "";
    for(Customer customer : customerlist)
    {
        if(pNr == customer.getPCode())
        {
            for(SavingsAccount account : accounts)
            {
                if(accountId == account.getAccountId())
                {
                    info = "Personnummer: " + pNr + "\nKontonummer: " + accountId
                    + "\nSaldo: " + amount + "\nRänta: " + SavingsAccount.RATE;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    return info; 
}


//the methods in Customerclass
public void addAccount(long pNr){
    accounts.add(new SavingsAccount());
}

public ArrayList<SavingsAccount> getAccount(){
    return accounts;
}


//methods from SavingsAccount
public int getAccountId(){
    return accountCount++;
}

public String toString(){
    String infoAccount = "\tKontonr: " + accountId + "\tKontotyp: " + accounttype +
    "\nSaldo: " + balance + "\tRäntesats: " + RATE;
    return infoAccount;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not useful to other users.

Comment: You could use the foreach-loop in your first method too (or even better, use a `Map`). What's with the `this.customer = customer;` and `this.account = account;` in the other method?

Comment: can you show your data?

Comment: @Kayaman Maybe this. is useless here. I have updated with my first try of printing out. Is there anything I have missed in any of the methods that doesn't connect between pNr and accountId?

Comment: Without the `this.` part it would be even more useless. I would remove both lines unless there's a good reason for it.

Comment: @djechlin - This has been retired as a close reason.  Please choose a different reason if you find this question worthy of being closed.

Comment: @demongolem I and many, if not most, high rep users are probably just going to stop answering questions if these questions are permitted. See several discussions on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @djechlin Please define what you mean by "these questions" or provide a link that explains this.  As I often tell posters who post unclear questions, "We are not mind readers"; but I'm no better at reading the minds of high-rep users as I am of newbies.

Comment: @ajb http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions/ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow/252531#252531

Comment: @djechlin Howcome is my question not useful to others? I'm new to java and thought this was a forum for help or am I wrong?

Comment: @MiaRaunegger yes, you are. Firstly, this is not a forum. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/183887

Comment: @djechlin Maybe my choice of words was wrong, but I'm surely only interested in getting a pure answer of what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I see enough code, but it looks like you're trying to set things up so that each `account` has an account ID.  However, your `getAccountId` method is going to return a different value each time it's called, even when called on the same `SavingsAccount`, because it will increment a counter each time it's called.

What you need to do is to declare an instance member such as `accountId` in the `SavingsAccount`, and set it when a new `SavingsAccount` is created:

```
accountId = accountCount++;
```

**That** is the only place you want to use the `++`.  Then, `getAccountId()` would return the instance member, without incrementing anything.