# compare two strings using loops in java insensitive case?

Tags: java, loops

Write a program to read two string and print “Equal” if they are the same case insensitive. For example :

- Input: Code Code

  - Output: Equal
- Input: Masr Masry

  - Output: Not Equal
- Input: Egypt EGYpt

  - Output: Equal

Note: You should use loops. Don’t use some existing method to check equality.

i'v tried this code and faild more than 5 times :(

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class equal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String st1=in.nextLine();
        String st2=in.nextLine();
        int len1=st1.length();
        int len2=st2.length();
        int y=1;
        if(len1==len2){
            char ch1=st1.charAt(0);
            char ch2=st2.charAt(0);
            int con1=ch1 , con2=ch2;
            if(con1==con2){
                for(int x=1;x<len1;x++){
                    char Ch1=st1.charAt(x);
                    char Ch2=st2.charAt(x);
                    if(Ch1==Ch2){
                        y++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(y==len1){
            System.out.println("Equal");
        }else if(y!=len1){
            System.out.println("Not Equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at `Character.toLowerCase`?

Comment: "You should use loops. Don’t use some existing method to check equality." -1. This is completely false.

Comment: @djechlin It seems like an assignment so he want's it complex way :D

Comment: @djechlin I think it's rules for his/her assignment.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc in that case this isn't useful for anyone else and should be closed. Way ahead of you though, already voted.

Comment: As a rule I don't answer homework questions, but have you considered converting all the characters to lower case using String's toLowerCase() method then comparing the resulting strings character by character? (Note that strings are immutable and toLowerCase returns a string.

Comment: @djechlin
This guy had tried something so lets try and help him out in his way

Comment: @djechlin  If he/she has tried and has shown the effort (and code), why not help?  Even if there is an easier way to do it (like  using `.equalsIgnoreCase`), maybe the purpose of the assignment is get the student thinking of how simple methods work internally.

Comment: Note that in the loop if at any point you see two characters that are not equal you can just return false you don't need to keep on looping because you know that they aren't the same.

Comment: Check if the strings are equal length. If they're not, you have a failure. Now you know the Strings are equal length. Loop over each character, and use the Character.toLowerCase() method to compare them to each other. If you have a failure, immediately return false. If you end having no failures, return true.

Comment: Also note that if you aren't allowed to use a toLowerCase function that you can roll your own compare ignorecase method with the knowledge that the int value of any Capital Character is offset by 32 (20 in hex) from it's lowercase. this only applies to letters though.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc because help vampires scare answerers away. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523820/creating-a-method-from-calling-two-classes-in-java#comment36091989_23523820

Comment: @djechlin *vampires scare answerers* ?? Also, that still doesn't change the fact OP tried and needs coding help.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc yes. Please see the several discussions linked and feel free to continue this conversation there. It is not SO's responsibility to help every coder who needs help because frankly that's not possible.

Comment: check the answer which I posted @VirusCD

Comment: @OmarKooheji It only works for ASCII letters, not all Unicode or even all Latin1 letters, although that's probably enough for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1:**

As user ZouZou mentioned, you can easily use:

```
char ch1=Character.toLowerCase(st1.charAt(x));
```

**Option 2:**

However, if you want to avoid Option 1, you can make your own method with `switch/case` statements (or `if/else-if`) statements.  You take in a character and return a the lower case version if it exists.  Else wise just return the current character given.

```
public static char charToLowerCase(char ch){
    switch (ch) {
        case 'A': return 'a'';
        case 'B': return 'b';
        //etc.  write rest of cases
        default:  return ch;
    }
}
```

Then in your main loop:

```
char ch1=charToLowerCase(st1.charAt(x));
```

**Option 3:**

Option 2 is a simple solution and not the most efficient, but it is easy to understand.  It's still very usable for this assignment.  If you want to change characters by manipulating the ASCII value of the characters, then take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719904/2498729) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16259296/2498729):

```
char toLowerCase(char c){
    if(c>=97 && c<=122)
        return (char) (c-32);
    else
        return c;
}
```

***NOTE***:  This example only deals with ASCII and not Unicode!

Comment: Why the downvote?  What's the point of downvoting if you don't explain your downvote (especially the mysterious first downvoter)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the solution with the switch case on letters is very bad. You could do ASCII manipulation instead much easier.

Comment: that switch case thing is hefty.

Comment: @Kon A simple solution for beginners is probably better for now.

Comment: now your answer looks clear...

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc I like simple, but the previous solution bordered on bad practice in my opinion. I've upvoted your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.. may be not the perfect one but should help your cause **(I would never prefer to do this way though)**

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
public class Equal {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String st1 = in.nextLine();
        String st2 = in.nextLine();
        int len1 = st1.length();
        int len2 = st2.length();
        int y = 0;
        if (len1 == len2) {
            for (int x = 0; x < len1; x++) {
                int Ch1 = st1.charAt(x);
                int Ch2 = st2.charAt(x);    
                if (Ch1 >= 65 && Ch1 <= 90) {
                    Ch1 = Ch1 + 32;
                }
                if (Ch2 >= 65 && Ch2 <= 90) {
                    Ch2 = Ch2 + 32;
                }    
                if (Ch1 == Ch2) {
                    y++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Equal");
        }

        if (y == len1) {
            System.out.println("Equal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Equal");
        }
    }
}
```